# Validate two tables and insert results in a new one

Tags: sql

I have two tables (`table1` and `table2`) and I have to validate if a value in a specific column from table1 exists in table2, and if so insert the result to a new table (which is composed with fields from table1 and table2).

For example:

Table 1 has columns like:

```
Imagem
Tipo_Backup
Periocidade
```

Table2 has columns like:

```
ClientName
Outcome
StartDateTime
EndDateTime
```

Table3 need to be composed like this:

```
Imagem (from table1)
Tipo_Backup (from Table1)
Periocidade (from Table1)
Outcome (from Table2)
StartDatetime (from Table2)
EndDatetime (from Table2)
```

Here is my code so far:

```
SELECT Imagem, periocidade, 
into LGP_tbl_ExecMBackups
FROM LGP_tbl_MapaBackups A
WHERE A.Imagem in
(select REPLACE (B.clientName,'_DB2','')
from Lgp_tbl_import_fx_bocada B)
```

I don't know how to complete the code to get table3.

Comment: Where did `LGP_tbl_ExecMBackups` and `LGP_tbl_MapaBackups` come from? Your sample query has no relationship to the schema you provided.

Comment: What are the table 1, 2 and 3 names?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
INSERT INTO LGP_tbl_ExecMBackups
SELECT 
A.Imagem,
A.Tipo_Backup,
A.Periocidade,
B.Outcome,
B.StartDateTime,
B.EndDateTime
FROM LGP_tbl_MapaBackups A
INNER JOIN Lgp_tbl_import_fx_bocada B
ON A.Imagem = REPLACE (B.clientName,'_DB2','')
```

But, it's look like there are no relationship between table1 and table2. If you have huge data, the query will take forever to finish.